# Get values from Asp.Net Core AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

On an Asp.Net Core 3.1 application I have the following section on AppSettings:

```
  "Logins": [
    {
      "Name": "Facebook",
      "Id": "fb_id",
      "Secret": "fb_secret"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Google",
      "Id": "go_id",
      "Secret": "go_secret"
    }
  ]
```

I am trying to get values, such as Id of Facebook, so I tried:

```
Configuration.GetValue<String>("Logins:Facebook:Id")
```

But this won't work ... How can I get the values?

Comment: `Logins` and `Facebook` are sections. Instead of reading strings, why not read the entire `Facebook` object though? Or read the entire array at once? You could use eg `Get` or `Bind` to load strongly-typed objects on startup, register with DI and inject them as needed

Comment: You should be able to use `Configurrattion.GetSection("Logins").Get<MyLogin[]>()` to load the entire array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All ASP.NET Core configuration gets converted into key-value pairs. In your example, you end up with key-value pairs that looks like this:

- `Logins:0:Name` = `Facebook`
- `Logins:0:Id` = `fb_id`
- `Logins:0:Secret` = `fb_secret`
- `Logins:1:Name` = `Google`
- `Logins:1:Id` = `go_id`
- `Logins:1:Secret` = `go_secret`

As this shows, there's no key named `Logins:Facebook:Id`, which is because the JSON structure uses an array. If you want to target the providers by name, update the JSON to use the following structure:

```json
"Logins": {
  "Facebook": {
    "Id": "fb_id",
    "Secret": "fb_secret"
  },
  "Google": {
    "Id": "go_id",
    "Secret": "go_secret"
  }
}
```

This creates the key-value pairs that you expect, e.g.:

- `Logins:Facebook:Id` = `fb_id`
- `Logins:Facebook:Secret` = `fb_secret`

Also, because these values are already strings, you can, if you prefer, just use something like this to read the value:

```
Configuration["Logins:Facebook:Id"]
```